# How to Make Nested JSON Object with Python

Tags: python, json

I need to make JSON output that looks like the following

```
{   "items": [
     "number": {
       "value": 23
       "label": test
    }
]
}
```

I've done something similar with the code below but I can't figure out how I need to nest number under items.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json

myjson = {'items':[]}
d = {}
d['value'] = 23
d['label'] = "test"
myjson.get('items').append(d)
output = json.dumps(myjson)
print output
```

That gives me

```
{
"items": [{
  "value": 23, 
  "label": "test"}
]}
```

Comment: What you posted is invalid JSON.  You can't have something like `["x": blah]`.  The colon can only occur inside `{}`, not directly inside `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input JSON isn't proper, it should be something like:

```
{ "items": 
    [ 
       {
       "number": 
           {
           "value": 23,
           "label": "test"
           }
       } 
    ] 
}
```

Besides that it can get messy, but accessing the resultant dict is intuitive.

```
 jdict = json.loads(yourjson)
 jdict['items'] => [{"number":{...}}]
 jdict['items'][0] => {"number":{...}}
 jdict['items'][0]['number']['value'] => 23
```

**Edit:**

Think you actually just wanted this:

```
myjson.get('items').append({'number': d})
```

You have to append a dictionary, not entries of a dictionary to items.

Comment: Could you please be more explicit with your code example to help me out? I think I understand where you are going but I could use a concrete example.